# Same folder/hdd is being shown 3 times in network. How to disable two of them

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, network-shares

When I open my desktop from my laptop (both are on same homegroup) It shows me same HDD three times. In below screenscht marked folder's are same HDD. How to keep only one.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they are all the same share? Maybe more than one computer is sharing the same share.

Comment: @Logman - I'm sure they are all same. No other computers in network

Comment: Open cmd prompt and type ">net share" and then ">net share aShareName /delete" to remove the share... if they are your shares... or to Computer Managements mmc Shared Folders